# Unable to import a package containing .pyc file

Tags: python, importerror, python-import

I have a folder hierarchy as below:

```
test\  
  dbtest.py
  lib1\
       __init__.pyc
       lib2\
         test.pyc
         __init__.pyc
```

In dbtest.py i want to import test.pyc

for that i have written following statement : `import lib1.lib2.test`

But when i try to execute that code i am getting following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have searched for it and found various alternatives like append to sys path and from keyword but nothing seem to be working.

Comment: what do you get when printing `sys.path` in `dbtest.py` ?

Comment: why do you want to import a .pyc file?

Comment: sys.path is showing path for python lib,site-packages,dll.

Comment: .pyc file is containing some encryption algo which i want to use

Comment: Are you sure the ImportError is referring to `lib1.lib2.test` and not something that `lib1.lib2.test` is trying to import?  Can you post the full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

1. Your `_init_.pyc` files should be `__init__.pyc`, but I suspect that is just a transcription error, or your error message would be different.
2. .pyc files are not portable across versions of Python.  Python 2.7 will refuse to run .pyc files created with 2.6, for example.
3. Your error message mentions a DLL, but you haven't told us about a DLL.  Do you have more information?

Comment: @pankaj-khurana and it should be `.pyc` and not `.pvc` (i guess it was a typo)

Comment: sorry it was typo mistake. i am running python 2.6.6 and pyc files were generated using same version. I don't have a clue about dll